# Overlapping in Order and ranking

Tags: combinatorics, find-the-order

For order and ranking questions there are a couple of the questions which require to find the total number of persons along with maximum and minimum condition which is difficult for me to comprehend. A slight explanation with a schematic is most certainly welcome.
Particularly the overlapping situation is difficult for me to comprehend here.
Please refer to the picture. [image] Where are these conditions coming from?

Source: [LINK](https://www.bankersadda.com/ibps-po-prelims-reasoning-ability-mini-mock-22-order-ranking/)

Comment: Welcome to PuzzlingSE! Your question has likely been downvoted because you have linked to an outside site rather than post the puzzle here. To prevent your question being closed, you should put the puzzle here in full and include the link to the site as a reference to where you found the puzzle.

Comment: @Tonks I have provided the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The picture seems to demonstrate an ambiguous problem with 2 possible answers.

We're given that Ram is 18th from the left end of the row, and Sumit is 23rd from the right end, and that there are 5 other boys in between Ram and Sumit.

It is possible that Ram is to the left of Sumit, with 5 boys in between, and there are 18+5+23 = 46 boys in the row. This is the non-overlapping answer because the 17 boys to the left of Ram don't include Sumit, and the 22 boys to the right of Sumit don't include Ram.

The row looks like this (where R = Ram, and S = Sumit).

`.................R.....S......................`

However, there is a 2nd answer, because it is possible that Ram is to the right of Sumit, with 5 boys in between. This is the overlapping answer, because Sumit is among the 17 boys to the left of Ram, and Ram is among the 22 boys to the right of Sumit.

In this case, the number of boys in the row equals 18 + 23 - 5 - 2 = 34.

`...........S.....R................`

Comment: Thanks for replying but what about the between condition that is there? Please justify that.

Comment: "Between" is specified in the question, in the image that you included. The question states that there are 5 boys in between R and S.

Comment: between>least-2 and contrary. Please justify where the condition is coming from.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What "condition" are you referring to?

Comment: Please check the shortcut  condition in the image.(Left portion).Where are the things being derived from?